# Modify a macro like CTRL+F

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, excel-2007

Friends, 
I am using the following code to find a NAME in my work sheet and to enter their status. But this macro is not compatible if a duplicate or Similar name exist. Friends can you help me to sort out this. What I need is I need this macro to activate the search NAME Cell and then a VB box with OK & NEXT button has to appear. if the activated NAME is exactly the one I am searching, then I will click the OK button then it should display the "Enter Employee Status" box and as continue in my code, But If I press NEXT, the macro should search the next similar NAME and activate it, This process should continue until I click the OK button.    (Same like CTRL+F function with an additional Status entry button)

Friends, Please help me

```
      Sub Button1848_Click()
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Dim BeginCol As Long
                  Dim endCol As Long
                  Dim ChkRow As Long
                  Dim rng As Range
                  Dim c As Variant

                  BeginCol = 6
                  endCol = 370
                  ChkRow = 7
                  For Colcnt = BeginCol To endCol

        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ChkRow, Colcnt).Value = Date Then

        Name = InputBox("Enter Employee name")
        Cells.Find(What:=Name, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate

       ActiveCell.Select

        Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ChkRow, Colcnt).Rows("2:500")
                        For Each c In rng
                            If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c.Row, 2).Value = ActiveCell Then
                            If c.Value = "" Then
                    Status = InputBox("Enter Employee Status")
                              c.Value = Status

                                  End If
                              End If
                         Next c
                      Else
                         'MsgBox "No Employee in this Name"
                   End If
                  Next Colcnt
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    End Sub
```

Comment: Friends,  requesting some help from you dears...Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is to create a UserForm. You can do so by right-clicking your VBAProject in the Visual Basic editor and picking "Insert" -> "UserForm".

Design it to include the buttons you need and add the code to the buttons. Once it's done, you can display it by calling `<UserFormName>.Show`.

Finally, you need to set the `ShowModal` property of the UserForm to `False`. This will allow you to use the workbook while the form is open, hence mimicking the behavior of the CTRL+F dialog.